# Foundation and vertical align. Better use custom media queries?

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, vertical-alignment, zurb-foundation

I'm about to build my very first responsive website and I wanted to use Twitter Bootstrap. I found out they're in a transitioning phase and the documentation is non-existent, so I switched to Foundation v4, the Vanilla CSS option one.

I've tried it making a very simple layout and it's a blast, I really love it!

Considering it works on the 960gs I based my design on that..only to found out during the pre-code phase(project still has to be approved but I have some spare time and I'm already starting to code it) that Foundation doesn't come with a vertical align system!

I've made a layout which is basically like this:

[image]
And this is how the header(the rest works fine) should look on mobile:

[image]

Basically **I'm experiencing three problems**:

1) how does Zurb allow you to reposition content vertically? I know the header sucks this was but they adjusted the menu bar to "touch" the big image and the social media icons to be half way to the left image which is the logo..and I don't know how to do it

2) will the objects automatically place themselves like in the second picture in the mobile version?

I swear I searched for over one hour to find out how to space or reposition content vertically better and I can't seem to be able to do it..

And **here comes my third question**:

3) considering I'm not familiar with media queries, should I find a way to make it work in Foundation(which is already set up) or it's better for me to make custom media queries with a layout like this? I'm actually having some problems with the media queries, that's why I'm using a framework at the moment.

Thanks in advance for the help, hope there's a way in Foundation 4 to make this work without getting crazy!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean "reposition"? have you tried `position` or `margin-top` or anything like that? Show us what you already tried